# Github Action Maven CI/CD to Docker Hub

Tags: docker, maven, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I want to implement CI/CD to a Basic Java Maven project with Github Action and deployment to Docker HUB.. i set up everything and followed this  [tutorial](https://medium.com/@alexander.volminger/ci-cd-for-java-maven-using-github-actions-d009a7cb4b8f)

here is my main.yml file: (without the build)

```
  publish-job:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      needs: [build_and_test]
      steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
          with:
            java-version: 17
        - run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml -DskipTests
        - run: mkdir staging && cp target/*jar-with-dependencies.jar staging
        - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
          with:
            name: Package
            path: staging
  
  build-docker-image:
    name: Publish to Docker Hub
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [build_and_test]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        run: docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }} -p ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
      - name: Build Container image
        run: docker build -t ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REPO }}:latest .
      - name: Publish Docker image
        run: docker push ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REPO }}
```

getting this error:

[image]

The Build is successful, but something seems wrong with the publish job

Comment: Hey @Scoopex, few hints on how to improve your question: (1) copy/paste error messages instead of screenshots (makes it easier to search), (2) only include relevant parts of the YAML (since the error is from the first job, why include the second?)

Comment: Also note that the checkout and setup-java action are available in `v3` (this is not going to solve your problem though)